# How to write a function that will define a keyboard shortcut

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to write a function that will set a shortcut programmatically, as in the MRE below:

```lisp
(defun my/shortcut-definer (keypress end-message)
  (interactive)
  (global-set-key
   (kbd keypress)
   '(lambda () (interactive) (message end-message))))

  (my/shortcut-definer "C-x x x" "Hello!")
```

I am tantalisingly close, but when I enter the chosen keyboard shortcut, I get the error:

`Symbol’s value as variable is void: end-message`

I think the problem is when defining the shortcut I wanted it to evaluate `end-message` but instead it included the symbol. How can I make it evaluate `end-message` in the lambda? (Assuming that is the error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/how-to-evaluate-a-symbol-in-a-lambda-function-when-defining-it) I found a solution to this problem as follows:

```lisp
(defun my/shortcut-definer (keypress end-message)
  (interactive)
  (global-set-key
   (kbd keypress)
   `(lambda () (interactive) (message ,end-message))))
```